# How to take db backup of agilefant (my sql database) using batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, batch-processing

as we have installed agilefant and Bugzilla, i need to take the back up of both in mysql by using batchfile.. please do help

```
@echo off
echo Running dump..
C:\mysqlserver\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqldump -u root agilefant>D:\Agilefantbackup\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql
echo Done!
```

This is my batch file, im able to run this command by using command prompt but im not able to execute the same by using command prompt

Comment: Is `C:\mysqlserver\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>` a part of the batch file?

Comment: ya that is a part of batch file

Comment: That shouldn't be a part of the batch file!

Comment: i am new to this can u sagest how it should be

Comment: Remove the highlighted text from the batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@echo off
echo Running dump..
pushd "C:\mysqlserver\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysqldump -u root agilefant>"D:\Agilefantbackup\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql"
echo Done!
popd
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you 'accept' the answer then someone in future will know which answer worked for you.